# Where is the flaw in the bank robber's argument?

Tags: fallacies

In Harry Harrison's *Stainless Steel Rat* books, the protagonist is an antihero thief.  At one point he makes the argument that bank robbery is a victimless crime and is, in fact, a societal good overall.  And while the argument, like everything in the books, is meant to be read in a tongue-in-cheek tone, I wonder if there are any formal flaws in the logic.  It goes like this (paraphrased):

- The money is taken from the bank, not from individual depositors, so the bank's customers are not harmed.
- The bank has insurance and will get the money back, so the bank is not harmed.
- The insurance company is specifically in this line of business.  The cost of the reimbursement to the bank is expected and planned for by its actuaries, and the burden is spread out over all its customers and shareholders.  Worst case scenario, everyone gets half a cent less on their dividend checks.  No real harm done there.
- Meanwhile, money that was just sitting around in a vault is now in the hands of the robber, who is going to spend it, providing economic stimulation that would not have happened otherwise.  Benefit #1.
- The spectacle of the robbery draws attention, providing work for journalists and entertainment for the masses.  Benefit #2.
- As the police attempt to chase the robber down, it provides exercise and job experience for them.  Benefit #3.

Is there a good way to counter this argument with logic?

Comment: Premise 3 is false, as we saw in a dramatic fashion during the 2008 crisis. Worst case scenario is that insurance companies cannot make up for massive losses, banks go bankrupt and then customers and shareholders lose their money. Of course, this won't happen from a single robbery, but it is potentially a contributing factor. Other costs to be weighed against the benefits, which are overlooked here, include creating perverse incentives for *everyone* to become a robber, with imminent social collapse if it happens. The root flaw here is disregarding cumulative effects of multiple actions.

Comment: What would happen if we all did this?

Comment: @user48488 "Then I'd be a damn fool to do any different!" -- From Catch 22

Comment: @user48488 There are plenty of things in society that are seen as good regardless of the fact that they would break down entirely if everyone made use of them at the same time, from hospitals to public highways.  So I don't consider this a particularly persuasive counter-argument to the bank robber.

Comment: The bank's & insurance company's dividends would end up low (insurance premiums will go up), harming mainly pensions, which focus on owning shares in companies like banks. It fails the categorical imperative, no economy would be possible if every or even did this. And no sorting algorithm is proposed on who is 'allowed' to do it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler ... A judgement of good or bad is only levied when the question is answered in any case, which you haven't done.  We're still waiting for your answer, which I predict you'll avoid again, if past behaviour is any predictor of future behaviour.

Comment: @user48488 ... good is bad and black is white.

Answer (score 1):

Banks do not let money sit around in their vaults.  They lend it out.  That's how they pay for their operations.  Furthermore, the people who borrow it are willing to spend money for it, thus showing their higher degree of commitment to using it wisely than the bank robber.

Furthermore, this means that the amount of money in the bank is limited.  Generally to about as much as the bank expects to be used within a short time frame.  By stealing it, the robber inflicts injury on those who need to have cash in hand.

Furthermore, the insurance company is an inefficient use of money.  It's better than the catastrophic losses inflicted without the insurance, but to put money back into the economy, it is much more effective to not rob the bank, thus decreasing the premiums paid and thus giving people more in their dividend checks forever, so they can spend it.  Especially since this decreases the overhead of the insurance company, which, economically speaking, is pure loss.

Finally, he is attacking the concept of private property as such.  Even a thief who is careful to harm only those who can endure it can not ensure that those who are corrupted by his example will stop where he would stop.

Comment: The difference is that with fractional reserve banking, they keep enough money in hand to handle those cases.

Comment: This question is not about *petty* bank theft.

Answer (score 0):

Banks, like casinos, operate on statistical margins and the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). In other words:

- Casinos allow gamblers to take individual risks that are carefully calculated so that (over large numbers of gamblers) the amount lost by gamblers is somewhat more than the amount won. That difference is the casino's profit margin.
- Banks lend money to organizations and individuals, carefully calculating loan rates so that (over large numbers of loans) the amount lost to defaults is somewhat less than the amount earned in interest. That difference is the bank's profit margin.

Savings and and checking accounts and such are offered by banks as a way to gather diffuse funds from individuals that can be lent out as a whole. Opening an account in a bank is a bit like investing, without the potential risks or windfalls that come from playing the stock market.

If one cheats or steals from a casino or a bank it throws off their marginal calculations, cutting into or destroying their profit. Do it badly enough and one 'breaks the bank', meaning the organization no longer has sufficient funds to cover their loses, honor their own debts, pay back investors, or even continue basic operations. They may try to collect insurance, but insurance companies also work on margins so that merely passes the buck. They may try to call back their loans, crushing the people and companies depending on those loans. They may try to declare bankruptcy, crushing investors who fall outside federal or private insurance programs. Any way it goes, someone is going to get crushed.

You can think of this by analogy to a cargo ship. A cargo ship floats because the hull creates just enough of an air-pocket that the air's buoyancy offsets the weight of the cargo and ship. The smaller the margin between buoyancy and weight, the more cargo it can carry, and the more profit it can make. But siphon off just a little of that air pocket — hardly any at all, or so it might seem, compared to the size of the ship itself — and the whole thing goes to the bottom of the ocean in a hurry. When we work at scale like this, messing with margins is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

All arguments are fallacious.

```
The bank has insurance and will get the money back, so the bank is not harmed.
```

It seems you base all your arguments on this, but your observation is quite superficial. Banks are not simple enterprises as you seem to understand them to be. Banks make a lot of money, but in several subtle ways. A robbery affects them all. For example: if I am the bank owner, I will never get another insurance at the same price; I will have less clients; I will get a bad reputation; I will have multiple problems to make stock/bonus movements... in final terms, I will lose A LOT OF money.

```
The money is taken from the bank, not from individual depositors, so the bank's customers are not harmed.
```

The robber is taking a part of my money; it is affecting an entity which makes me a bit richer by being a bit richer. If the bank loses some money, I certainly will do the same.

```
The insurance company is specifically in this line of business. The cost of the reimbursement to the bank is expected and planned for by its actuaries, and the burden is spread out over all its customers and shareholders. Worst case scenario, everyone gets half a cent less on their dividend checks. No real harm done there.
```

Again, this is a completely superficial observation, without knowing the technical issues behind. At least, in simple terms: paying an insurance is a loss for insurance companies and the government, which in final terms, affects me; when the insurance money is used otherwise, that's direct social benefits for me.

```
Meanwhile, money that was just sitting around in a vault is now in the hands of the robber, who is going to spend it, providing economic stimulation that would not have happened otherwise. Benefit #1.
```

Again, apparent and superficial. Money that is not earned is bad spent money. And working people works for their benefit, not for the benefit of society. With such thinking, better go living in Laos, Cuba or Venezuela, where -just due to the lack of stable money, conservation of value- people effectively work for others, not for themselves.

```
The spectacle of the robbery draws attention, providing work for journalists and entertainment for the masses. Benefit #2.
```

Hooray! Let's promote crime in order to make media enterprises richer! No. The time society invests on solving a problem is the time society could have used to do what it has to do.

```
As the police attempt to chase the robber down, it provides exercise and job experience for them. Benefit #3.
```

Your proposition is to have more crime, in order to grow the police forces. What a bad idea. We would prefer not having a police, like multiple european cities: more healthy social behavior, less crime, less police.